# redirect nohup output to another file

Tags: nohup

I am running a command with nohup on one of my servers, the output file has become too big and I predict that the process would need an extra month of execution before it completes. Is there a way to change the nohup output file while the process is running?

Comment: Maybe you could enlarge the file system. Are you using LVM or raid?

Comment: The process holds an open file descriptor, so modifications to the filesystem won't affect the file to which the file descriptor points (so mounting over it, moving, deletion,... are out of the question). The only things that might work are modifying the file in-place (rewriting the file as empty). Relevant link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980283/truncating-a-file-while-its-being-used-linux

Comment: @orion writing the file in-place made matters worse. nothing is being written to the file anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this neat little utility that enabled me to redirect the output to another file and everything is working fine now. The utility is called reredirect and can be found in: https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/

A simple command like: `reredirect -m FILE PID` gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

The *idea* given in one of the comments is generally what's done, even if the link to another question has an erroneous (and unaccepted) answer.

To truncate the file in a POSIX shell use:

```
cat /dev/null > _name_of_file_
```

Not `cp` as one answer in the link suggests. Of course, you might want to copy the old file to a different filesystem or to a remote location if you want to save it first.

In low-level terms, the difference is that you are opening the *existing* file and with its inode and truncating it. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html and the `O_TRUNC` option.

Some other things that work in special cases. I sometimes check `/etc/logrotate.d` (or some other suitable log rotation program) to see how that swaps out files. Some commands like apache2 have a `reload` command that cause it to load a configuration file and in the process reopen log files.

Comment: The problem is when I did that the process stopped writing to the file completely

Comment: I suspect you used `cp`, not `cat > /dev/null. Or in more low-level POSIX libc terms you are doing an open in truncate mode. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html  . From your running processes standpoint it won't know the difference if on the nohub you used ">".

Comment: @ZaidAmir Another thing you should try to convince yourself this works is to run the thing again (maybe in a test scenario) and see that it works. If not feel free to add more details. The key idea here is to think about and try the remedies _before_ you need them.

Comment: Well I AM trying to convince my self but its not, as I said now the process stopped writing completely while I can see it working and generating new entries in the database. I cannot restart the task now as that will make me lose about 40 days of processing.

Comment: So try it on another computer or in the same computer in a slightly different environment with reduced/test data. If you are spending 40 days of processing,  then definitely this is the kind of stuff you should have been considering _beforehand_. But it is never too late to learn from this and  start.